# pass paremeter through .load from previous ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tearing my hair out on this one.... sure it just the structure of my function.

Basically I make a Ajax call within an Ajax loaded tab. The call made within writes a record to the Database and returns a value. I can alert the value fine but when I try to use it as a data parameter in my .load() call it doesn't get passed?

As they are in the same success function I just thought (Stupidly?) that I could easily reference it!

```
$('#convert-2-booking').click(function(e) {
    var quoteid = $(this).attr("title");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'tabs/convert-2-booking.asp?Planner_ID='+$('#convert-2-booking').attr("title")+'',
        data: quoteid,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(responseText){
            var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='images/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";
            var loadUrl = "tabs/booking.asp";
            bookingid = responseText;

            //above gets correct returned id.

            $("#bookingtab").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl, { 'bookingid': bookingid } ); // not here though :(
            alert(bookingid) // alerts the correct id here too!
            setTimeout(function() {
                            
                // move to bookings tab after 3 seconds

                $("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active", 3 );
                // load correct record into tab
            }, 3000);
        },
        error: function(responseText){
            alert("NOT:"+responseText);
            //alert(responseText);
            $("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active", 2 ); //load previous tab itself if returns error..
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you see the parameter in the Network tab of developer tools?

Comment: Instead of trying to time it with `setTimeout`, try using `$('something').promise().done(function() { /* do stuff */ });`

Comment: it shows the 1st call in Network - to booking.asp. It also shows the 2nd, but the bookingid parameter is not there :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up deciding to store the id in a session for the few seconds i need it. Not ideal, but a workaround for now, and enough to allow me to demo to my client.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing it via "booking.asp?bookingid=..."
Like this:

```
.load(loadUrl+"?bookingid="+bookingid)
```

It's a workaround tho; I'm not sure why load() doesn't do the same thing thru your array... Maybe it's because you only check GET variables on server side and load() gives you POST...?

Comment: `.load()` uses GET, not POST.

Comment: jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/load/) is not very clear about that. There are examples like "... Same as above, but will POST the additional parameters to the server ..." - and then it shows an example which does almost exactly the same you did.  So maybe we don't know enough about its bad habits.

Comment: You're right. At the beginning it says it's equivalent to `$.get()`, but later says _The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed._ That's really strange, IMHO.

Comment: It is, indeed. But that was the last place for the problem to hide.

Comment: im going to try the suggestions above - i thought it best to read the documentation again - and can see why I still can't understand! - will keep you posted.

Comment: tried the above idea by dkellner, still ignores it. Wondering if there is another way to do what I need to:

1). pass an ID server side
2). process and generate new id
3). move to next tab from where this was called
4). load content based on new id into the tab selected in (3).

Anyone got a clearer way of doing this? Nice when documentation doesnt solve the issue ! ;)